# Intercepting windows mouse click

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, spy++

Could somebody guide me to find out a windows API function to use in order to intercept a mouse click on certain button on a particular window. I have used spy ++ and learned that when I move the  finder tool on to a button or any thing in the window I am able to read information about handler and other things. So is there a way to intercept mouse clicks and inject our code before some action is performed. Thank you very much for sharing any idea about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of a couple different ways to approach this:

1. You can use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) to install a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` message hook in the target window's thread, and then the hook callback can process window messages like `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` on the target window itself, or `BN_CLICKED` on the target window's parent.  The caveat is the callback needs to be implemented in a DLL so the hook can be injected into the target process.  You can get the target window's thread ID using [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx).

   A variation of this would be to have `SetWindowsHookEx()` install a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook instead, and then you can use [`PostMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) to post a custom window message to the target window.  The hook callback can then use [`SetWindowLongPtr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) or [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) to subclass the target window directly, and/or its parent, for further message processing.
2. You can use [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) to monitor `EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED` events, such as button clicks.  No DLL is needed if you use the `WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT` flag, but the caveat is the installing thread needs an active message loop so events can be handled across process boundaries.

Comment: This is the best answer, but it needs code examples

Answer (score 2):

You will need to call [SetWindowsHookEx](https://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=setwindowshookex&oq=setwindowshooke&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3871j0j7) API to set a windows hook. Here's an article with source code, that demonstrates its usage: [Hooks and DLLs](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037/Hooks-and-DLLs)