# On Windows, intercepts and change a click event system-wide

Tags: windows, mouse, low-level

My researches led me to that thread, but it is not exactly what I need:
[Intercepting windows mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239779/intercepting-windows-mouse-click)

How could I intercept all mouse clicks, system-wide, for, say, the right click, and change its behavior? For instance, if I would want the right click to do nothing, on my whole running Windows OS.

Should I keep looking for a solution involving SetWindowsHookEx(), or rather have another approach, maybe more low level?

Thank you